# Maximum integer value for a variable in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, modeling, agent, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to increment an agent property on each tick in the "go" procedure. But it will not increment after some value above 10000's.

1. What could be the issue? Is my code wrong?
2. What is the maximum value that can hold by a variable?

```
to go
  ask people with [diagnosis = "infected" and tested? = true] [
    set infected-time infected-time + 1
  ]
  ask people with [infected-time > 80000] [
    set color white
    set infected-time 0
  ]
  ......
  ......
  tick
end
```

Comment: NetLogo uses double-precision floating points to store number values, meaning the largest number it can store is very, very large (2 to the 52 power):  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#math

Comment: my guess is that, at some point, the person is no longer infected so the `with` condition excludes them

Comment: Seems to be a logical error in my code.